# MySQL IF() Function does not work anymore

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, collation

I have a database running for over two years now. Recently, I decided that it would be a good idea to change the collation of the whole schema and all the tables to one other than `utf8_general_ci`. Shortly after that, I received complaints from the user, upon which I reverted all the changes I had made to the schema and I thought I could sleep easy. But after a while, I received yet other complaints and got to work to pinpoint the issue, and so did I.

It turned out that one statement in one of the stored procedures did not return the desired result. It is something like this:

```
    SELECT
        A, -- BIGINT(24)
        B, -- BIGINT(24)
        C, -- BIGINT(24)
        D, -- ENUM('VALUE_A', 'VALUE_B', 'VALUE_C')
    INTO
        @W, @X, @Y, @Z
    FROM
        `my_table`
    WHERE
        some_field = in_sproc_param; -- in_sproc_param (IN VARCHAR(64)) -> parameter to the stored procedure

    SET @T = @W + @X;

    SET @Q = IF(@Z <> 'VALUE_C' AND @T >= @Y, 'TRUE', 'FALSE');
    -- '
```

The IF() function always returns `FALSE`, regardless of what values you pass to it. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfef227e27f85c2ae65202549c4a40fb).

Comment: You may need to force/cast collation on your strings. The documentation for [strcmp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) will probably be helpful.

Comment: I have tried `STRCMP()`. It just won't do it.

Comment: Select the values for the `@Z`, `@T` and `@Y` after the select. It could be that the `WHERE`-clause does not find matches due to collation problem and gives `NULL` values to the variables. When comparing `NULL` values to anything, the result will be false.

Comment: Running `SELECT` on all the variables return the expected values. The problem is that `IF()` returns `FALSE` in any case, so I believe there has to be something inside is that is going wrong.

Comment: I didn't mean for you to necessarily use strcmp; I was referring to the collation manipulations demonstrated on it's page.

Comment: @SCilek try **DROP** procedure then recreate it. Don't alter and check.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`  The problem may be there.

Comment: expert came .